# Monte Carlo simulation in forecasting?

Tags: c#, .net, finance, data-mining

I am a physicist. Also i have some information about Monte Carlo simulation. i want to learn financial forecasting with Monte Carlo. Do you have any idea? What do you think financial decisions programming ? How is the future of financial software with Monte Carlo Simulation?

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to google Nassim Nicholas Taleb on the topic.

Comment: This returns references to his book "Fooled by Randomness".  Definitely a book to be read (I'm reading it at the moment), but it's not going to help getting started programming simulations!

Answer (score 3):

Start with the [Monte Carlo methods in finance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_methods_in_finance) Wikipedia article, and don't ignore [warnings against using this method](http://registeredrep.com/mag/finance_why_advisors_say/) for financial planning.

Comment: These warnings are made by people of doubtful competence: "James A. Shambo of Lifetime Planning Concepts in Colorado Springs, relying on Monte Carlo is dangerous because the system treats the current market not as a starting point but as merely one of all possible environments. “Monte Carlo can predict a 20 percent return because the simulation started at a 7 P/E and then doubled,” Shambo notes. “But how relevant is that if your real world starting point is a 30 P/E and your real client is a 70-year-old widow worried about how her portfolio will be affected over the next 10-to-20 years?”- pfft

Comment: @quant_dev: Then by all means, ignore the warnings.  Nothing bad can happen.

Comment: The point is,  *any* decent MC simulation always takes the current market as a starting point. He's fighting straw men.

Answer (score 1):

This book is a classic: [http://www.amazon.com/Monte-Carlo-Methods-Finance-Jaeckel/dp/047149741X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047149741X)

Answer (score 0):

If you're a physicist interested in quant finance, check out Emanuel Derman's "My Life as  a Quant" http://www.emanuelderman.com/media/MyLifeAsAQuant.pdf